# Use share in IOS

Tags: ios, swift

I think, that everybody use `share` feature in your iDevice. So I decided to add this feature to my mobile-manager app, but I don't know how to start. Share link in documentation or other information about this thing, please
[image]
[image]

Comment: Your question is very difficult to understand. Please rephrase it and show us what you've tried so far.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the [tour] and review [ask].

Comment: Start by going to google (or your favorite search engine) and search for `swift UIActivityViewController`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use UIActivityViewController. It’s very simple you’ll get it!